# How to constrain pig parameter names

Tags: parameters, apache-pig, substitution

Given the pig parameter $MYPARAM, when constructing strings such as

`A = load 'foo/$MYPARAMbar';`

pig complains that $MYPARAMbar is an undefined parameter.

Curly brackets have been proposed to constrain parameter names in situations like this: http://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution#Future_Features

But for the time being, are there any good workarounds (for pig v0.11.1) for using parameters to construct strings for use in LOADs, FILTERs, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be no for Pig 0.11.1.  The best you can do for the time being is to pass fully qualified parameters.  For example, this does **not** currently work like you would want:

```
A = load 'foo/$MYPARAMbar';
```

so on the command line you should just pass -param filename=${MYPARAM}bar and do

```
A = load 'foo/$filename';
```